# Unable to get connect to FTP due to error: Connection closed by remote host on https://secureftp.abcfinancial.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ftp, sftp

I am uunable to connect to SecureFTP via my proxy.I am connecting to FTP to download PDF statements whihc are stored at https://secureftp.abcfinancial.com

I have tested the proxy and checked it with their Support team, it does not not seem to have any issue. The problem here is that secureftp has closed its remote connection.

Shared below is my code GetStatement service

```
class GetStatementsForCandidate
  include Service
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :candidate, Candidate
  attribute :response, Array, default: []
  attribute :month, String

  def call
    connect_to_ftp
    return_response
  end

  private

  def connect_to_ftp
    begin
      ssh = Net::SSH.start(ENV['STATEMENT_FTP_HOST'], ENV['STATEMENT_FTP_USERNAME'], password: ENV['STATEMENT_FTP_PASSWORD'], proxy: proxy)
        ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp|

          # if candidate.old_gateway_id
          #   sftp.dir.glob("/archive/#{candidate.old_gateway_id}/statements#{month}", "**/*.pdf") do |month_folder|
          #     next if ['.', '..'].include? month_folder.name
          #     self.response << month_folder.name
          #   end
          # end
          sftp.dir.glob("/archive/#{candidate.gateway_id}/statements/#{month}", "**/*.pdf") do |month_folder|
            next if ['.', '..'].include? month_folder.name
            self.response << month_folder.name
          end  
          

        end
      # end
    rescue => e
      self.response << e.message
    end
  end

  def return_response
    self.response
  end

  def proxy
    quotaguard = URI(ENV["QUOTAGUARDSTATIC_URL"])
    Net::SSH::Proxy::HTTP.new(quotaguard.host, quotaguard.port, user: quotaguard.user, password: quotaguard.password)
  end
end
```

Shared below is controller where GetStatement Service is used

```
  def index
    if @fetch.account.try(:gateway_id).present?
      if params[:month]
        statement_names = GetStatementsForCandidate.call(candidate: @fetch.account, month: params[:month])
        @statements = process_data(statement_names).reverse unless statement_names.last.include? "no such file"
      end
    end
  end
```

It looks like the firewall is setup in reverse.  I can reach it from my laptop, but not wiht my proxy

```
> sftp secureftp.abcfinancial.com
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I cant find any admin/support for https://secureftp.abcfinancial.com/ and at this point i am clueless on how to proceed further.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: first you need to successfully execute sftp from the command line. If you can't do that, then adding Ruby on top just makes the problem more difficult. If it doesn't work from the command line, try using the -v, -vv, or -vvv options to see where the protocol is failing.

Comment: I was able to connect to sftp using Terminal ```admin1@CHETUIWK521:~$ sftp rtmsftp@secureftp.abcfinancial.com -v
Enter password: 
Enter password: 
Enter password: 
rtmsftp@secureftp.abcfinancial.com's password: 
Connected to secureftp.abcfinancial.com.
sftp> 
``` however, with he proxy i am facing issues. this code was initially working, but i guess it stopped recently after an SSL update